# How to pass parameters between one cloud formation to another cloud formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

How to pass parameters between one cloud formation template file to another cloud formation template file in aws ?
I am not talking about the nested templates , as I understand they are seperate resource blocks within one CFT only , please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [the official documentation for cross-stack references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html) and how it can be used.

The basic idea is that you'll have shared resources put into their own stack so that other stacks can reference those resources. This leads to less copy/paste in all of your cloud formation templates.

For example, you might have multiple related web applications that use the same security group rules for their servers. Rather than defining the same exact security group multiple times in each cloud formation template for each web application, you can put that security group into its own template/stack, declare the security group id as an output, and then in all of your web applications' cf templates, you can import that security group id and reference it for your instance's security group. This leads to less duplicate code, and a separation of concerns, as a network engineer can manage the security around the VPC/subnets/security groups and you only need to worry about your servers/applications.

Comment: Awesome! I noticed your question was a year ago without an official answer so I thought I'd chime in.

Comment: Well done for answering this question with the documentation first. As normally first hand information is better than second hand.

Answer (score 4):

It only makes sense to pass parameters between stacks, not between templates - the templates are just JSON structures.

You can do it like this:

In the first template, create output values like this:

```
"Outputs" : {
    "ParentVPC" : {
        "Value" : {"Ref":"VPC"},
        "Description" : "VPC ID"
    },
    ...
}
```

Then, in the second template, create parameters like this:

```
"Parameters" : {
    "ParentVPC" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
    },
    ...
}
```

When creating a stack from the second template, call `describe-stack` on a stack created from the first template to get the output values, and pass them as parameters to `create-stack`.

Comment: how do I call the second template from the first template ? Currently I am using this method which obviously  is not right .. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147966/passing-parameters-in-nested-cloud-formation-templates` which i

Comment: There is no way to do that - the second stack does not exist when you create the first one, so there is nothing to look up.

Comment: If you want to share data between the two stacks, you can always create a third stack that they both access.

Comment: Also, you can always have code running on an EC2 instance call describe-stack to look up any stack you want at runtime.

Comment: Thanks @bsvingen, I will try these suggestions and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pass parameters from one CFT to another: 
I defined the parameters in the child CFT and passed their values in the parent CFT . Here is an example:

Parent CFT (CFT1)

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Chef HA AWS Template",
  "Parameters" : {
         "ChefServerAWSRegion" : {
               "Description" : "Choose deployment target from list",
                "Type" : "String",
                "AllowedValues" : ["deveast1", "qaeast1", "prodeast1","prodwest1","prodwest2"],
                "Default": "deveast1"
         }
   },
   "Mappings": {
              "deveast1":
              {
                        "chefstackurl":{
                            "frontend" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/tbdchef/frontendinstance.json",
                        },
                        "a":
                        {
                          "sgBlueStripe": "sg-81c09fe5",
                          "sgSharedServices": "sg-82c09fe6",
                          }
               }
    }
}
```

Child Template (where the values are defined , and I have kept my logic to build the infrastructure:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Chef HA AWS Template",
    "Parameters": {
        "sgBlueStripe": {
            "Description": "sgBlueStripe",
            "Type": "String"
        },  
        "sgSharedServices": {
            "Description": "sgSharedServices",
            "Type": "String"
        }     
    }
   "Resources": {
        "FrontendInstance": 
        {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {
                "DisableApiTermination": "true",
                "SecurityGroupIds": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "sgBlueStripe"
                    },
                    {
                        "Ref": "sgSharedServices"
                    }
                ],
              }
        }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two primary ways to orchestrate cloud formation templates:

- Use [Cloud Formation Nested Stacks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html). This allows one cloud formation stack to create and manage a separate stack. You can retrieve the outputs of the Stack by using `Fn::GetAtt` if you need them for other resources on the stack.
- Orchestrate with a non AWS tool like [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/cloudformation_module.html) or plain bash scripts. Ansible makes it easy to retrieve the outputs of one stack and pass to anther, for example:

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are really looking for is to create a Lambda that will retrieve the outputs of another cloudformation and expose them in your running cloud formation.

It is very well explained here : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-cross-stack-ref.html

You then retrieve the outputs from the `NetworkStack` like so.

```
"NetworkInfo": {
  "Type": "Custom::NetworkInfo",
  "Properties": {
    "ServiceToken": { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["LookupStackOutputs", "Arn"] },
    "StackName": {
      "Ref": "NetworkStackName"
    }
  }
}
```

and use them by doing :

```
"SubnetId" : { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "NetworkInfo", "PublicSubnet" ] }
```

I am using it myself and it fits well with the free execution minutes you get each month for Lambda.